# how to set default interpolator for all animations in android?

Tags: android, android-animation

I know how to set it for the one animation, but I would like to have it for all animations in my app. For example to set it in style in MyAplication theme

Comment: can't do that, mission impossible

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is impossible. You should handle each case like this:

```
  TranslateAnimation translateanim = new TranslateAnimation(-100, 0, 0, 0);
        translateanim.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
        translateanim.setDuration(1000);

        startAnimation(translateanim);
```

Or you can create your own animation class with already setted interpolator and use it in all places of your app.